# Passing in table name and row info into an INSERT INTO stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass into the procedure the table name and the values without mentioning column names because I want to be able to use this on any table.

`@row` would be csv string like 'test','123'

My code causes an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @table NVARCHAR(100),
    @row  NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @table+ 'VALUES (' + @row + ')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: what is the error?  FYI, you need whitespace between @table and 'VALUES..   Right now, your SQL would read INSERT INTO MYTABLEVALUES ....

Comment: I would run away from this type of procedure as fast as possible. It is vulnerable to sql injection and is incredibly brittle. If you don't pass exactly the right number of values for the table this is going to blow up. There are so many reasons a "one procedure to rule them all" approach is bad.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

> SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test 
       @table NVARCHAR(100), 
       @row NVARCHAR(max) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @table+ '] VALUES (' + @row + ')'
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END
```

**Note**: if you select table name `dynamic` and you are pass single values it means the table has single columns
If you pass any other table and table has multiple columns your insert statement not work.

Comment: . . You should explain why you think this works.  Why is it better than the OP's query?

Comment: Table variables can be dangerous.  If you're going to use something like this then the variable needs to be examined and validated before executing things like ```INSERT```.

Comment: All you did was add a predefined schema name to the code posted by OP. How is this any improvement?